# "Missing full declaration for private type.." in Ada

Tags: ada

I'm having a problem using a package ADS file in Ada.
I'm getting an error of "Missing full declaration for private type LETTER".
How do I deal with it?

this is the code I wrote:

> package LETTER_SPEC is
>
> type LETTER is private;
>
> procedure DATE_OF_LETTER (THE_LETTER: in out LETTER; DATE: STRING);
>
> procedure RECIPIENT_NAME (THE_LETTER: in out LETTER; NAME: STRING);
>
> procedure SUBJECT_LINE (THE_LETTER: in out LETTER; SUBJECT: STRING);
>
> procedure TEXT_OF_LETTER (THE_LETTER: in out LETTER; TEXT: STRING);
>
> procedure SENDER_NAME (THE_LETTER: in out LETTER; NAME: STRING);
>
> procedure PUT_LETTER (THE_LETTER: in LETTER);
>
> private
>
> type PTR_LETTER is access STRING;
>
> type LETTER_DATA is
>
> ```
>    record
>
>       DATE_OF_LETTER: PTR_LETTER;
>
>        RECIPIENT_NAME: PTR_LETTER;
>
>       SUBJECT_LINE: PTR_LETTER;
>
>        TEXT_OF_LETTER: PTR_LETTER;
>
>        SENDER_NAME: PTR_LETTER;
>
>    end record;
> ```
>
> end LETTER_SPEC;'

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ada complains because you declare in the private part a `LETTER_DATA` type and not a `LETTER` type.